# Присвоить указателю отрицательное значение

Tags: c++

Как присвоить указателю отрицательное значение числа? вот пробовал это сделать но программа не работает

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int *p = (int*)-6;
    cout << p<<endl;
    cout << (int*)*p<<endl;
    int *ptr = nullptr;
    ptr = (int*)-0x28ff44;
    cout << ptr<<endl;  
}
```

Comment: Указатель - это переменная которая хранит адресс. Как адресс может быть отрицательным? Адресс - это посути смещение от нулевого адресса. Как порядковый номер на планке ОЗУ может быть минусовый?

Comment: @rikimary2013,Погуглите значение указателя может быть отрицательно

Comment: @Mr. Hello_world На некоторых платформах, как, например, IBM mainframe, у указателей может быть установлен знаковый бит, но тем не менее этот знаковый бит игнорируется при обращении к памяти с помощью такого указателя. Вы можете вычитать целые числа из указателей, получая снова указатель, если он не выходит за границу массива (одиночный объект в этом случае рассматривается как массив из одного элемента).

Comment: Присвоить-то можно любое значение. А вот доступна ли вам память по этому адресу (и как его интерпретировать (это вообще-то зависит от типа компа (архитектуры))) -- это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: а что значит не работает? падает или не собирается? это две большие разницы

Answer (score 4):

Значение указателя может выглядеть как отрицательное число (я говорю исключительно о x86/amd64 платформе, на других платформах все может быть по другому). И это штатная ситуация. Просто нужно правильно это все понимать.

Итак, адрес в памяти - исключительно положительное беззнаковое число. Ячейки памяти это то, что можно посчитать, а считать предметы числами меньше нуля нет никакого смысла.

Но есть одна заковырка - в комьютерах все считают единицами и нулями. (да, были троичные компьютеры, но дальше эксприментов они не пошли). А раз все отображается нулями и единицами, то что бы определить, что значит данная конкретная единица или ноль нельзя. Они все равны как на подбор. Поэтому есть соглашения, что если это 4 байта, то это 32битное число. И если там адрес, то все биты (то есть нули и единицы) отображают целое положительное число и есть соглашение, как по этому набору получить физический адрес в микросхеме/диске.

Для математических рассчетов иногда нужны отрицательные числа. Для этого нужно где то ещё хранить знак. Так как знак может иметь два значения, то как раз напрашивается выделить для него один бит. И тут кому то пришла в голову идея использовать старший бит для хранения знака. Рассмотрим конкретный пример.

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

это `-1` в большинстве современных компьютеров, если для хранения используются 32-битные числа. Но это и `4294967295`, если мы считаем, что в данных четырех байтах хранится беззнаковое число (например, адрес). Но если мы решили, что в этих 4 байтах хранятся символы в кодировке (это важно) cp1251, то это просто четыре буквы «я».

Подытожим: адрес *может* выглядеть (это ключевое слово!) как отрицательное число. Но только потому, что было выбрано такое отображения значения адреса. На самом деле адрес можно хоть строкой отображать. Главное уметь правильно это интерпретировать.

Но подойдем с другой стороны. А зачем задавать адрес непосредственно числом? я вижу только несколько причин — это работа с железом, и нужно указать адрес порта ввода-вывода или работа с микроконтроллером, где иногда приходиться ручками распределять программу и ее данные по памяти. В обычных прикладных программах подобное обычно говорит об ошибках.

Вернемся к коду, который упомянут в вопросе. Код «работает» (в смысле компилируется и запускается, хотя я бы добавил ещё `return 0;` в самый конец). Но вот только результат немного странный (на первый взгляд).  Вроде записывали адрес `-0x28ff44`, а в консоли отображается `0xffd700bc` Но если перевести оба числа в бинарную форму (учитывая, что первое знаковое, а второе беззнаковое), то они совпадут. До последнего бита. Если после вышенаписанного все равно есть непонимания - читать о [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)) до полного понимания.
Если же этот код скомпилировать 64-битным компилятором, то результат может быть ещё интереснее - `0xffffffffffd700bc`. Но это лишь потому, что указатели на 64битной платформе 64-битные.

Comment: оч. крутой ответ. Адрес должен быть числом, потому что есть поддерживаемые стандартом операции с адресом. Например, сдвиг на n байт при работе с массивом. Отсюда и представление адреса не может быть случайным, потому что важно, чтобы A+n действительно указывало на адрес n-ой буквы строки А, а значит значения разных адресов и их представления должны быть определенным образом связаны между собой.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *ptr = (int *)-5;
    cout << ptr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Компилируется и исполняется. Выводится положительное значение, но это естественно происходит при приведении типа. Разыменовывать даже не пытался.

Answer (score 0):

Стандарт не гарантирует ничего с указателями, кроме того, что они могут указывать на любые объекты (память на куче, стеке, функции и т.п.), необходимые при работе программы и некоторых особенностей устройства памяти.
Адреса действительно могут быть отрицательными, обычно область ядра ОС, но в Windows адресное пространство процесса всегда не отрицательно, и все известные мне реализации компиляторов под Windows это учитывают. 
Иными словами, если Вы собираетесь под Windows, то Вы пытаетесь присвоить отрицательное значение переменной типа unsigned int.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, компилятор g++, результат отличный от Win7, но также положительный.